# Get category ID from category slug (not working)

Tags: categories

I found this code, which apparently gets the category ID from the category slug:

```
  $category = get_category_by_slug('category-name'); 
  $id = $category->term_id;
```

But when I try to implement it into the following code, it doesn't work:

```
<?php
//list terms in a custom taxonomy using wp_list_categories 

$category = get_category_by_slug( 'military' );

$args = array(
  'taxonomy'     => 'product_cat',
  'orderby'      => 'name',
  'show_count'   => 0,
  'pad_counts'   => 0,
  'hierarchical' => 1,
  'title_li'     => '',
  'depth'        => 2,
  'child_of'     => $category->term_id
);

?>

<ul class="test">
<?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
</ul>
```

I'm attempting to show only the child categories of a specific parent category. If I just type the category ID for "child_of" then it works perfectly. But using the above code, it continues to show all categories. Unfortunately I need to do it via slug, not via ID.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### You can't use [`get_category_by_slug()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/category.php#L155) with a custom taxonomy.  You need to use [`get_term_by()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by).

```
$category = get_term_by( 'slug', 'military', 'product_cat' );
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that. Thank you! However, I tried replacing the line **$category = get_category_by_slug...** to match what you wrote above, and it still did not work. Do I need to change the "child_of" line as well?

Comment: Can you dump the $category object to make sure it exists.  `var_dump( $category );` After the call to get_category_by_slug().

Comment: I did the dump, and it gave me this: object(stdClass)#771 (10) { ["term_id"]=> string(3) "144" ["name"]=> string(31) "Military Bands" ["slug"]=> string(11) "military" ["term_group"]=> string(1) "0" ["avhec_term_order"]=> string(1) "0" ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> string(3) "144" ["taxonomy"]=> string(11) "product_cat" ["description"]=> string(238) "Watch Straps" ["parent"]=> string(1) "0" ["count"]=> string(3) "163" }

Comment: Ah! I had spelled category wrong in my code when I typed in your new line. Argh. It's always the stupid mistakes. Thank you -- this worked!

Comment: See for example without shouting capitals: [get_category_by_slug](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_by_slug) how to get the ID.